# Closet door doesn't close completely from the top side - IKEA closet and hinges

Tags: hinges, closet

We bought [IKEA closets](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/hjaelpa-standard-hinges-60331200/) with several hinges of this specific type:

You can adjust the screws to shift the closet door horizontally, vertically and the depth towards the closet.

With one specific closet the top right of the closet won't close.  The bottom right side closes against the closet, leaving a gap of about 2 centimeters deep on the top right side.  I've tried adjusting the hinges to adjust the depth and horizontal placements endlessly with little to no improvement.

**Question:** Does anyone know how to solve this or is the door simply uneven?

(*There are small cushions attached on the inside which makes it look like the bottom right is not touching the closet, but it is.
It's not easy for us to detach the hinges again to verify if the problem is the door itself.*)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the closets installed on a level surface and plum walls?

Comment: Yeah, the floor is level.

Comment: The cabinet enclosure needs to be squared at all corners, meaning the bottom must be level both directions  and the sides and the back must be squared at 90° to the bottom.  Both hinges must be adjusted together in order to achieve proper alignment.

Comment: Right. This isn't a hinge issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a long straight edge (4-6' long, depending on the height of the cabinet) on the door (maybe use the level you used to ensure that the cabinet itself was vertical) to ensure that the door itself is flat and not warped. Though they seem to take pretty good care of these in shipping, things happen.

If you're certain the door is flat, use an accurate ruler to ensure that the mounting holes in the cabinet wall are all the same distance from the front edge of the cabinet. Despite these all being machine made, it's possible for the holes to be misdrilled. I recently purchased & assembled a (non-IKEA) flat-pack armoire and both side panels were incorrectly drilled - the bottom 2 door hinges would mount, but the top ones wouldn't. They sent me replacement sides and all is good now.

It is possible, BTW, to remove the screws for the hinges. With a little care you can install them several times if necessary. The particle board these are made of *will* get chewed up, but it is doable (again from personal experience). If you determine that the problem is with the door, you should be able to exchange it. Remove the screws from the door since it (and any damaged holes) is going to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with an Ikea Besta door. Turns out that a clear plastic door bumper was wedged inside (portion attached to the door) and prevented the hinge from folding to 90 degrees completely. Always make sure that the hinges are clear of these or screws as they are packaged all together in a plastic bag. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: this helped me! 30 mins of fooling around with it and I saw this and wouldn’t you know there were two bumpers lodged inside the hinge